# slideshow images work locally but not working on my website

Tags: javascript, html

I am using html and javascript to create a photo gallery.

when I am testing the code on my local machine it works fine but when I put it on the website it didn't work.

the problem is the minature photos appear but I can't click on them its like empty link!

This is the code ( I use it from the internet) and this is the link to the code

http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=image_slideshow

```
<div id="dhtmlgoodies_slideshow">
<div  id="previewPane">
    <img src="images/gallerie/image111_max.jpg">
    <span id="waitMessage">Loading image. Please wait</span>    
    <div id="largeImageCaption"></div>
</div>
<div align="center" id="galleryContainer">
    <div id="arrow_left"><img src="images/gallerie/arrow_left.gif"></div>
    <div id="arrow_right"><img src="images/gallerie/arrow_right.gif"></div>
    <div id="theImages">
    <!-- Thumbnails --> 
    <a href="#" onClick="showPreview('images/gallerie/image111_max.jpg','1');return false"><img src="images/gallerie/image111_min.jpg"></a> 
    <a href="#" onClick="showPreview('images/gallerie/image112_max.jpg','2');return false"><img src="images/gallerie/image112_min.jpg"></a> 
    <a href="#" onClick="showPreview('images/gallerie/image123_max.jpg','3');return false"><img src="images/gallerie/image123_min.jpg"></a> 
    <a href="#" onClick="showPreview('images/gallerie/image124_max.jpg','4');return false"><img src="images/gallerie/image124_min.jpg"></a>
     <a href="#" onClick="showPreview('images/gallerie/image125_max.jpg','5');return false"><img src="images/gallerie/image125_min.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" onClick="showPreview('images/gallerie/image126_max.jpg','6');return false"><img src="images/gallerie/image126_min.jpg"></a>


<!-- Image captions --> 
            <div class="imageCaption">(1)</div>
            <div class="imageCaption">(2)</div>
            <div class="imageCaption">(3)</div>
            <div class="imageCaption">(4)</div>
            <div class="imageCaption">(5)</div>
            <div class="imageCaption">(6)</div>
<div id="slideEnd"></div>
```

**the script**

image_slidshow.js

```
var displayWaitMessage=true;    // Display a please wait message while images are loading?


var activeImage = false;
var imageGalleryLeftPos = false;
var imageGalleryWidth = false;
var imageGalleryObj = false;
var maxGalleryXPos = false;
var slideSpeed = 0;
var imageGalleryCaptions = new Array();
function startSlide(e)
{
    if(document.all)e = event;
    var id = this.id;
    this.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[0].src = 'images/gallerie/' + this.id + '_over.jpg';
    if(this.id=='arrow_right'){
        slideSpeedMultiply = Math.floor((e.clientX - this.offsetLeft) / 5);
        slideSpeed = -1*slideSpeedMultiply;
        slideSpeed = Math.max(-10,slideSpeed);
    }else{
        slideSpeedMultiply = 10 - Math.floor((e.clientX - this.offsetLeft) / 5);
        slideSpeed = 1*slideSpeedMultiply;
        slideSpeed = Math.min(10,slideSpeed);
        if(slideSpeed<0)slideSpeed=10;
    }
}

function releaseSlide()
{
    var id = this.id;
    this.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[0].src = 'images/gallerie/' + this.id + '.jpg';
    slideSpeed=0;
}

function gallerySlide()
{
    if(slideSpeed!=0){
        var leftPos = imageGalleryObj.offsetLeft;
        leftPos = leftPos/1 + slideSpeed;
        if(leftPos>maxGalleryXPos){
            leftPos = maxGalleryXPos;
            slideSpeed = 0;

        }
        if(leftPos<minGalleryXPos){
            leftPos = minGalleryXPos;
            slideSpeed=0;
        }

        imageGalleryObj.style.left = leftPos + 'px';
    }
    setTimeout('gallerySlide()',20);

}

function showImage()
{
    if(activeImage){
        activeImage.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=50)';
        activeImage.style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
    this.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=100)';
    this.style.opacity = 1;
    activeImage = this;
}

function initSlideShow()
{
    document.getElementById('arrow_left').onmousemove = startSlide;
    document.getElementById('arrow_left').onmouseout = releaseSlide;
    document.getElementById('arrow_right').onmousemove = startSlide;
    document.getElementById('arrow_right').onmouseout = releaseSlide;




    imageGalleryObj = document.getElementById('theImages');
    imageGalleryLeftPos = imageGalleryObj.offsetLeft;
    var galleryContainer = document.getElementById('galleryContainer');
    imageGalleryWidth = galleryContainer.offsetWidth - 80;
    maxGalleryXPos = imageGalleryObj.offsetLeft;
    minGalleryXPos = imageGalleryWidth - document.getElementById('slideEnd').offsetLeft;

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') >= 0) {
        var arrowWidth = document.getElementById('arrow_left').offsetWidth;
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.style.position = 'absolute';
        el.style.left = arrowWidth + 'px';
        el.style.width = (galleryContainer.offsetWidth - arrowWidth * 2) + 'px';
        el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        el.style.height = '100%';

        document.getElementById('galleryContainer').appendChild(el);
        el.appendChild(document.getElementById('theImages'));
    }
    var slideshowImages = imageGalleryObj.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
    for(var no=0;no<slideshowImages.length;no++){
        slideshowImages[no].onmouseover = showImage;
    }

    var divs = imageGalleryObj.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
    for(var no=0;no<divs.length;no++){
        if(divs[no].className=='imageCaption')imageGalleryCaptions[imageGalleryCaptions.length] = divs[no].innerHTML;
    }
    gallerySlide();
}

function showPreview(imagePath,imageIndex){
    var subImages = document.getElementById('previewPane').getElementsByTagName('IMG');
    if(subImages.length==0){
        var img = document.createElement('IMG');
        document.getElementById('previewPane').appendChild(img);
    }else img = subImages[0];

    if(displayWaitMessage){
        document.getElementById('waitMessage').style.display='inline';
    }
    document.getElementById('largeImageCaption').style.display='none';
    img.onload = function() { hideWaitMessageAndShowCaption(imageIndex-1); };
    img.src = imagePath;

}
function hideWaitMessageAndShowCaption(imageIndex)
{
    document.getElementById('waitMessage').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('largeImageCaption').innerHTML = imageGalleryCaptions[imageIndex];
    document.getElementById('largeImageCaption').style.display='block';

}
window.onload = initSlideShow;
```

***Update***

when I have opened the console web the error is:
                             [11:36:48,021] GET http://www.mess.tn/mywebsite/scripts/image-slideshow.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not found 11ms]

Comment: Can you show your javascript code ?

Comment: Can we also see a link to the live site?

Comment: Are the images and the Javascript file containing the `showPreview` code uploaded to the Server too? And has the Server the same folder structure? Did you use a `<base href="...">` tag in your `head` section? This can sometimes lead to problems between local and online development

Comment: Paste the code into a jsfiddle and share the link.

Comment: @msbodetti the website is down because is under construction I just test on it

Comment: Enable firebug (or get it), go to "Net" panel, and check if all resources (scripts, images) are being downloaded from server correctly (200 code).

Comment: @user2609840 From your update, it looks like your html cant find the slideshow javascript file to run the actual slideshow. I suggest putting the necessary image-slideshow.js in it's correct folder for your html to find it!

Comment: Are you sure your js is really in http://www.mess.tn/mywebsite/scripts/image-slideshow.js path?

Comment: @Alesanco yes I am sure, I even put the javascript code in the html page and the same error persist

Answer (score 0):

did you spell your js file name correctly?

your error shows: `image-slideshow.js` Not found

while you're sample file says: `image_slidshow.js`